# Open Facebook Mobile Web App in webview from browser

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to Open a Facebook Web App into native facebook app from any browser?

I have a mobile website where I need to place a button "Launch Facebook App".. When user click this button, I want to open my mobile web app inside native facebook app.. I've tried few scheme like **fb://** but it only opens up the facebook app in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:** No it is not possible to open a mobile web app into the native facebook app's webview.

**On iOS** there are some unofficial URL schemes available to open the native facebook app (and some special pages) via a simple browser link, e.g.:

```
<a href="fb://profile">Your FB Profile</a>
```

More schemes: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Apparently there is no URL to open a web app into the webview of the native facebook app.

**On Android** there is no possibility at all to open the native facebook app via the browser.